# LARAVEL 5 :: Language switch? Error: Use of undefined constant language - assumed 'language'

Tags: php, error-handling, laravel-5, lang

So I'm trying to make a bilingual website that can switch from english to portuguese and vice-verse through a single click.

I'm getting this error: `Use of undefined constant language - assumed 'language'`

In a random view I use:

```
<form action="{{ URL::route(language-chooser) }}" method="post">
    <select name="locale">
        <option value="en">English</option>
        <option value="pt">Portuguese</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Choose">
    {{ Form::token() }}
</form>
<p>{{ trans('homepage.home') }}</p>
```

The LanguageController:

```
class LanguageController extends BaseController {

    public function chooser()
    {
        Session::set('locale', Input::get('locale'));
        return Redirect::back();
    }
}
```

The route:

```
Route::post('/language', array(
    'before' => 'csrf',
    'as' => 'language-chooser',
    'uses' => 'LanguageController@chooser',
));
```

I'm getting that error and I can't figure why... Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings should be wrapped in quotes. `""` or `''`. And your route name is a string so:

```
<form action="{{ URL::route('language-chooser') }}" method="post">
```

Comment: I don't undestand why people gave you downvote, your answer is quite good and should solve problem

Comment: @kmlnvm Probably because this question is really on the edge of just being too simple / a typographical error... At least that's the only reason I can think of

Comment: Oh yes! Didn't even noticed that! Thank you. Don't know who gave you a downvote but here's my upvote!

Comment: well, even that you shouldn't get any downvote, only question should

Comment: Yes but most of the times are those simple syntax errors that prevent us from getting things done.

Comment: Why should the question get a downvote? None should get a downvote. We're here to learn and help each other.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, whomever did it. Sad people.

Comment: @Hyperion Don't worry too much about a downvote or the user who did it. Life goes on... (Start worrying if every question you ask get's downvoted or closed, then you're doing something wrong)

Comment: That usually doesn't happen. I couldn't care less, just doesn't make sense for us to get downvotes, that's all.